# Dynamically load classes that need classpath reference in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dynamic-class-loaders

I'm making a small console program which loads all the class files in a folder as "plugins", so that the program can be customizable by adding new classes.

Here is the problem: a plugin uses the SQL library to provide a simple querying system to a database. In order to include the jdbc driver it has the following code:

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
```

I compiled it adding the driver jar to the classpath:

```
javac -classpath ./libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar sqlquery.java
```

When I run the main jar which loads the plugin's .class file, even though I specify the driver jar in the program classpath, it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` when calling the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class.

What can I do?

Comment: You need the library on the classpath when running the program too.

Comment: I am doing so, I'm running the program via the shell command `java  -classpath "./plugins/libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar" -jar main.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `-jar` or `-cp` to load the classes into the classpath, **you can't combine the two**.

Try this:

> java -classpath "main.jar;./plugins/libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar" sqlquery.java